# How to import relative_url_for conditionally from Frozen-Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a website using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) that I want to freeze using [Frozen-Flask](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/), but also have the site run live.

I've followed [the documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#flask_frozen.relative_url_for) and set the `FREEZER_RELATIVE_URLS` config option to `True` only when freezing the site. This functions correctly, replacing `url_for` with `relative_url_for` in the template engine.

How do I also get it to use `relative_url_for` in my Python code only when a config option is set?

I guess I need something like:

```
if config['FREEZER_RELATIVE_URLS']:
    from flask_frozen import relative_url_for as url_for
else:
    from flask import url_for
```

However, if I try to access `flask.current_app.config` with the other imports in my `views.py` I get an error: `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access `current_app` outside of a view, so there's no app context to tell Flask what `current_app` points to.  Create a helper function that will pick which url function to call when it is called, rather than deciding at import time.

```
from flask import current_app, url_for as live_url_for
from flask_frozen import relative_url_for

def url_for(endpoint, **values):
    if current_app.config['FREEZER_RELATIVE_URLS']:
        return relative_url_for(endpoint, **values)

    return live_url_for(endpoint, **values)
```

Use this `url_for` helper inside your views rather than the other two functions.  You can also replace the `url_for` function used in Jinja templates with this function.

```
# during app creation
from helpers import url_for
app.add_template_global(url_for)
app.context_processor(lambda: {'url_for': url_for})
```